# QWebEngine & QWebChannel: transport object `qt.webChannelTransport` disappeared after page reload

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, sockets, qtwebengine

I created the web channel between my application and `WebEngine` in order to have exposed `QObject` on web side in JavaScript but the channel are lost after page reloading or in case if I click link to another page.

I think I need to recreate the channel on page reload but I didn't manage to do it. I tried to do it on page load, progress and finished slots but only got `js: Uncaught ReferenceError: qt is not defined`.

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->webEngineWidget->load(QUrl("qrc:/index.html"));
    page = ui->webEngineWidget->page();

    channel = new QWebChannel;
    channel->registerObject("external", &exposedObject);
    page->setWebChannel(channel);

    connect(page, &QWebEnginePage::loadStarted, this, &MainWindow::onPageLoadStarted);
    connect(page, &QWebEnginePage::loadProgress, this, &MainWindow::onPageLoadProgress);
    connect(page, &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, this, &MainWindow::onPageLoadFinished);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onPageLoadStarted()
{
    qDebug() << "Loading started";
}

void MainWindow::onPageLoadProgress(int progress)
{
    qDebug() << "Loading in progress: " << progress;
}

void MainWindow::onPageLoadFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "Loading finished";
}
```

Channel is created on the page side using `qwebchannel.js`:

```
<h1>Page</h1>
<a href="other.html">Other Page</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
<script>

var webChannel = new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel){
    window.external = channel.objects.external;
});

</script>
```

Full code of the example is here: https://github.com/DanmerZ/QWebChannels-example

Video: https://monosnap.com/file/ZTOgj1QH06VRVF3ogmXln07eOVXXCW

**P.S. This error is only for Qt5.7, I checked Qt5.6.1 and the channel works just fine.**
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52209?jql=text%20~%20%22QWebChannel%20reload%22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug, fix will be in Qt5.7.1, please see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53411 and http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/commit/?h=dev&id=ca6762abde85fe3104ec4f064b85319474ba2deb