# Sharing (Q)WebChannel between C++ and QML

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I would like to expose some C++ objects to JS. By now I have the objects correctly exposed to QML using the modifiers `Q_OBJECT` `Q_POPERTY` `Q_INVOKABLE` and so on. That part is working properly.

Of course, in C++ side I'm creating a WebChannel and exposing an object with something like:

```
QWebChannel *channel = new QWebChannel();
channel->registerObject("test", prueba);
```

On the other hand, I have a QML file where I'm using `WebEngineView` and `WebChannel`. I was wondering how can I connect the channel between C++ and QML.

I have seen many examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394130/qwebengine-qwebchannel-transport-object-qt-webchanneltransport-disappeared) but I don't know how to integrate it with QML.

Any idea?

Comment: have a look on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867334/how-to-pass-value-from-qml-to-javascript-in-qwebengineview])

Answer (score 2):

You should not create a new `(Q)WebChannel` both in QML and C++. In this way, you get two different channels.

If you want to access the channel in QML, I suggest to construct a `WebChannel`, which is in fact a `QQmlWebChannel` and inherits `QWebChannel`.

Comment: Lets suppose that I create `QWebChannel` only in C++. How can I tell QML to use that channel? All doc and examples that I have seen are quite fuzzy for me.

Comment: You can pass an object to qml using [`setContextProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty), but you should consider creating a `QQmlWebChannel` instead to be able to access all its properties in QML.